# Gridview Custom Paging and Hide Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging, rowdatabound

I have a code where I need to Hide certain Rows based on a condition. The Gridview is binded through Custom Paging with a Stored Procedure.

Problem right now is that, I have set to display 100 records per page in the gridview. Example in the first page, 10 Rows have to be hidden based on a condition, so the first page only has 90 records. It should be 100 records.

How do i bring data from the second page to the first page?

Fyi, i have been searching this solution for almost 2 days but no real solution have been founded.

**ASPX Code**, I take only a field from my actual code

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" CssClass="footable" data-sort="false" runat="server" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle="align:top;"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataText="<%$Resources:chienvh.language, xNoData%>"
                    GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:chienvh.language, xStaffID%>" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="8%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStaffNo2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StaffNo")%>' CssClass="upper-case" />
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>
                     </GridView>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
protected void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (somecondition)
        {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So i guess there is no way to filter the results based on the condition at the database level? If not I don't see how to achieve what you are looking for, the page is showing 100 records as specified, you are just changing the visibility of certain records.

Comment: can you update Your Question with the code from wich you are populating Grid view?